# Is it possible to resolve static members similarly to overloading the member access operator for another type?

Tags: c++

I am not sure what to call it, but is something like this possible as the commented out line reflects?

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    Test(T& t) : m_t(t) {}
    T* operator->() { return &m_t; }

private:
    T& m_t;
};

class A
{
public:
    static const int integer = 0;

    void function() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    Test<A> test(a);
    test->function();

    // Something similar to doing Test<A>::integer?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, why don't you do:

```
test->integer;
```

You can always access static members the same way as non-static ones (i.e. from an instance variable).

The other option would be to define in Test:

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
  typedef T value_type;
  // ...
};
```

In which case you will be able to do:

```
Test<A>::value_type::integer;
```

which will avoid the need of creating an instance of `Test<A>`.

At last, if you are using C++11 and `Test` follows the smart pointers conventions, then you will have:

```
std::pointer_traits<Test<A> >::element_type::integer;
```

which has the advantage to work even if you replace `Test<A>` with `A*`.

Answer (score 0):

No. In C++, "overloading" only makes sense for functions. Instead of mixing static and non-static items in a class, you could try making two separate classes, both with all non-static members. Return your value from a function call, rather than using a public static member variable.